# In React Bootstrap Dialog, How to refer component and its state, if the body of the dialog has a Component inside it?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Bootstrap Dialog(https://github.com/akiroom/react-bootstrap-dialog), which is opening up a Modal fine. I am using another React Component in the body of the Dialog. Once user clicks Ok, how can I refer the component and its state?

```
  let distributionListTable = <DistributionList name="distributionList" />;
        debugger;
        this.dialog.show({
            title: 'Select Users',
            body: distributionListTable,
            bsSize: 'large',
            actions: [
                Dialog.Action(
                    'Ok',
                    () => {
                        debugger;
                        //How to refer distribution list component and its state?
                    },
                'btn-fis'),
                Dialog.Action(
                    'Cancel',
                    (dialog) => {
                        dialog.hide();
                    },
                    'btn-fis-secondary'
                )
            ]
        });
```

Comment: I understood your question, but can I know why would you access DistributionList state in the OK method? I mean what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The Distribution List component is tabular data with checkboxes. On click of Ok, I need to find those distribution lists that are checked and populate the values in main component. Also, let me know if there is any other approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to move your Tabular data **one Level up** into the **Main Component**.

Use **handler** in Main Component passed in has **props** to update the **state**.

Now you will be able to access the **state** since it's been moved into a common ground.

Often in such situations, a Level up is the right solution.

There is one more solution to this **REDUX**, but using REDUX in such small situation's would be an overkill.

```
  Constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
        // TabularCheckBoxData
     }   
  }


  checkboxCheckHandler = (event,index) =>{
     // This code is to handle the checkbox click, use the index to update
  }

  let distributionListTable = <DistributionList name="distributionList" handler={this.checkboxCheckHandler}/>;
        debugger;
        this.dialog.show({
            title: 'Select Users',
            body: distributionListTable,
            bsSize: 'large',
            actions: [
                Dialog.Action(
                    'Ok',
                    () => {
                        debugger;
                        this.state; // Now access using this.state
                    },
                'btn-fis'),
                Dialog.Action(
                    'Cancel',
                    (dialog) => {
                        dialog.hide();
                    },
                    'btn-fis-secondary'
                )
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating an instance of distributionListTable and access the state object.
Something like this.

```
  let distributionListTable = <DistributionList name="distributionList" />;
  let distTable = new distributionListTable();

    debugger;
    this.dialog.show({
        title: 'Select Users',
        body:distributionListTable ,
        bsSize: 'large',
        actions: [
            Dialog.Action(
                'Ok',
                () => {
                    debugger;
                    function(){

            return distTable.state





          }
                },
            'btn-fis'),
            Dialog.Action(
                'Cancel',
                (dialog) => {
                    dialog.hide();
                },
                'btn-fis-secondary'
            )
        ]
    });
```

`

Comment: No, it does not help.